# check if all words present in a sentence

Tags: r

I am trying to get the output from words_check only if all the words in variable 'words' present in word_check.

I am trying to retrieve output from word_check.

My below code is not returning any value. Please help!

```
words <- "battery on key issue"

word_check <- c("battery on","key issue","battery on key issue")

pr_wd <- word_check[all(strsplit(word_check," ") %in% strsplit(words," "))]
```

### Expected Output:

```
"battery on key issue"
```

Comment: Break your code apart bit by bit. You're subsetting `word_check` based on whether *all* words from `word_check` are in `words`. `strsplit(word_check," ") %in% strsplit(words," ")` evaluates to false, false, true. Calling `all` on that obviously evaluates to false. Subsetting with `word_check[FALSE]` will get you an empty vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works, but it would be nice to have a couple other examples to test on.

```
word_check[unlist(Map(strsplit(words," "), strsplit(word_check," "), f = function(x, y) all(x %in% y)))]
#[1] "battery on key issue"
```